# Can't reach my VM

Tags: virtualbox

so I have an VM which used to work fine but now it doesn't.

Host: Win 10, Guest: Debian First Adapter: NAT, 2nd: Host only

I used it as a local web server. I also set a static IP. If I start the VM now, I get a "No Host Adapter selected" - which isn't really surprising since there is none. [No idea why] I only remember, that I wasn't able to use a bridged network adapter since that somehow bypassed Cyscos AnyConnect running on my host, thus I had no access to my LDAP Server, which I needed back then. The above settings solved it. But anyway, somethings wrong now.

So I guess I should create an Host Only Adapter in the Global Vbox settings. But how do I do that properly?

The VM was reachable via 192.168.56.101 [which shouldn't conflict with anything]. It was configured like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug etho0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

The Nat-Adapter in the globla settings is:

```
Network-Name: NatNetwork
Network-CIDR: 10.0.2.0/24
-Supports DHCP
-Support IPv6
```

and now I'm wondering how to properly set the host-only adapter. I'm not very experienced in all this especially in Vbox. So any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: This is totally straightforward process. You even have the default network setup used. All you have to do is click the green Plus in `File -> Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks` (VirtualBox Manager) and attach `Adapter 2` in machine's `Settings` to it.

Comment: that didn't change anything. Sure, I can "ping" the host only adapter itself but not my VM.

Comment: Please update question with following information 1. Can the VM ping the IP of the host adapter (ping 192.168.56.1 from VM)? 2. Routing table on VM (command `ip route show`) 3. Routing table on Host (command: `netstat -rn` ).